# Is there a way to make a UICollectionView row or header stay still a.k.a. freeze panes?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm wondering if there is a way to make a UICollectionView row or header stay still similar to the freeze panes function in a spreadsheet program.

I basically want the first column and row to stay still while the rest is pannable.

Is this possible to do with the UICollectionView?

Comment: Have you achieved this functionality?
If yes, then How?
I am stuck at same.

Answer (score 9):

I have found that the following code will set the first row/section as always visable and will scroll with the appropriate section/row:

```
- (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    NSMutableArray *attributes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < self.collectionView.numberOfSections; section++)
        for (NSInteger item = 0 ; item < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection: section]; item++)
        {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layout = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section]];
            if(section==0 || item==0)
            {
                UICollectionView * const cv = self.collectionView;
                CGPoint const contentOffset = cv.contentOffset;
                CGPoint origin = layout.frame.origin;
                if(item==0)
                {
                    origin.x = contentOffset.x;
                    layout.zIndex = 1022;
                }
                if(section==0)
                {
                    origin.y = contentOffset.y;
                    layout.zIndex = 1023;
                    if(item==0)layout.zIndex = 1024;
                }
                layout.frame = (CGRect)
                {
                    .origin = origin,
                    .size = layout.frame.size
                };
            }
            [attributes addObject:layout];
        }
    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: You also need invalidate layout on scrollViewDidScroll;

Comment: or use...

`- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange: (CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}`

Comment: where to add this code ? (p.s.: I translated it to swift) @stevekohls

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat this would be in your custom subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelements